# Is there a way to connect to the Google Adsense APIs with just an API Key?

Tags: ruby, google-api

I'm trying to build an application that will grab adsense reports data for my own account, is there a way to authorize this without firing up a browser for OAuth? Since this will be a command line client that will run on a server somewhere to build a time correlated report. Trying to do this in Ruby but preferably I should even be able to do this with curl

Comment: The AdSense Management API only supports OAuth, I'm afraid.

You can save your credential data so that you only have to run the authentication flow on the browser once, however, and then just load the saved credentials from a file or database.

Could you give us more details on your development environment, such as whether you are using the Google API client library for Ruby? I should be able to give you a full answer with some more details.